RabbitMQ Not Sending Messages to DLQ and Queue Arguments Not Visible
I am working on a Spring Boot application using RabbitMQ with a DLQ configuration. After throwing the AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException, the messages are not sent to the DLQ.
Here is the relevant code and configuration:
RabbitListener:
@RabbitListener(queues = "${notification.queues.dummy.name}", containerFactory = "notificationContainerFactory")
public void processDummyEvent(DummyEventDTO eventDTO, @Header(name = "x-death", required = false) Map<?, ?> death) {
    if (shouldRetry(death)) {
        log.error("death: {}", death);
        log.error("Consuming dummy queue...");
        throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException("Throwing from dummy queue after retrying...");
    } else {
        log.error("Throwing from dummy queue...");
        throw new ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException("Discarding message...");
    }
}

private boolean shouldRetry(Map<?,?> death) {
    return death == null || death.get(COUNT) == null || Integer.parseInt(death.get(COUNT).toString()) < 3;
}

RabbitMQ YML Configuration:
dummy:
  declare: true
  name: dummy-queue
  durable: true
  routingKey: dummy-queue-routingKey
  exchange:
    name: dummy-queue-exchange
    durable: true
    type: direct
  retryCount: 3
  arguments:
    x-dead-letter-exchange: dummy-dlq-queue-exchange
    x-dead-letter-routing-key: dummy-dlq-queue-routingKey
    x-queue-mode: lazy

dummy-dlq:
  declare: true
  name: dummy-dlq-queue
  durable: true
  routingKey: dummy-dlq-queue-routingKey
  exchange:
    name: dummy-dlq-queue-exchange
    durable: true
    type: direct
  arguments:
    x-dead-letter-exchange: dummy-queue-exchange
    x-dead-letter-routing-key: dummy-queue-routingKey
    x-queue-mode: lazy
    x-message-ttl: 10000

After throwing the AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException, messages are not being routed to the DLQ.
In the RabbitMQ management interface, the queue (dummy-queue) arguments related to DLQ are not visible.
How can I resolve this issue? Why aren't messages being sent to the DLQ after throwing AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException?
I noticed that the x-death header is coming as null.
Also, the queue arguments ara not visible in the RabbitMQ management interface.

We don't know what is that YAML configuration. Does not look like something supported by Spring Boot. Perhaps would be great if you can share with us some simple project to reproduce?

A queue supported by spring boot. The structure of all queues is like this and the configs are written accordingly. Queues are created in the rabbit interface and the listener method works. I cannot share the config files. According to this structure, where do you think the problem may be caused by? Do you have a solution suggestion?

You said the queue arguments ara not visible in the RabbitMQ management interface.. So, apparently that DLX config does not come to RabbitMQ to have respective policy on the queue. And I'm not familiar with that YAML you show. What parses it? This is really not Spring Boot auto-configuration.

this is really a spring boot configuration. do not focus on it. the queue is created and listener method works.  do you have a suggestion for this rabbit dlx binding case?

When you check in the broker after running you app, do you see those args for DLX? The point is that I cannot reproduce because I don’t know what to activate to read such a YAML. The queue might be just created by the @RabbitListener , but as plain as possible if no specific queue bean is declared.

what do you need?

A simple Spring Boot project to reproduce on our side and play with. I probably can come up with some solution for you, but it is not going to be based on the YAML you provide. Just because I don't know what library deals with such a config. Perhaps you talk about this project https://github.com/societe-generale/rabbitmq-advanced-spring-boot-starter which is out of my scope for support.
